# Python telebot does not send messages via dockerfile

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, telebot

I wrote a simple bot, to send results from main script

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("API")
cost_sum = str(data2['cost'].sum())
date = last_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
result = 'Capterra costs export done \n' + date + ' - ' + cost_sum

bot.send_message(chat_id, result)
```

And when i run it in Jupyter notebook or in Anaconda CMD i get message. But when i try to run it via dockerfile or in regular python i don't get any message, and any errors. Maybe i need to install some extra packages in dockerfile and regular python, but can't understand which exactly.

Comment: `telebot` is not defined.  where is the import ?

Comment: this is not the reason, the import is in the main script. And this script is working in Jupyter notebook, but don't in via dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this issue is to change imported package from telebot to telegram, and use this code for api access

```
bot = telegram.Bot("API")
bot.send_message(chat_id, result)
```